# how to send a system message to campfire, using API?

Tags: api, campfire

I've seen something like this in GitHub blog:

[image]

The question is: How to send a system messaget (the one with green background)? I really want to send deploy message that way, it would really help our team chat. Or is it all userscripts? :(